# Why does my program prompt for input over and over?

Tags: java

> You will write a Java program to play the game of Pico, Fermi, Bagel. Here are the rules of the game:
>
> The computer will generate a "secret" three digit number at random. The first number will not be 0, and all the digits will be different. The user tries to guess the number. If the user guesses correctly, then the game is over.
>
> If not, the computer gives a hint and the player tries again. The hints:
>
> - For each digit that matches the secret number in the proper place, the computer prints "Fermi"
> - For each digit that matches, but not in the proper place, the computer prints "Pico"
> - If none of the digits match, the computer prints "Bagels"
>
> The program will have a main class and a Bagels class. The bagels class will call 3 other methods to
>
> 1) generate the secret number
>
> 2) determine whether the current guess is a winner
>
> 3) evaluate the current guess and print hints

**My issue**: When I run my program, it asks me to enter a 3 digit number, but then it just repeatedly asks me to enter 3 digits over and over. I'm pretty sure the problem has something to do with the methods in my Bagels class. My compiler is saying that the `generateSecretNumber` and `printHint` methods are unused. The only thing is that I'm not sure how to go about making it so they are used.

Main class

```
package assignment.iii;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class AssignmentIII {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int playagain = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to play?", "Message", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        while (playagain == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            Bagels myBagels = new Bagels();
            myBagels.playGame();
            myBagels.randNumber = 0;
            playagain = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to play again?", "Message", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        }
    }
}
```

Bagels class

```
package assignment.iii;

import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Bagels {
    public int randNumber; 
    private int Guess; 
    private int Rand1, Rand2, Rand3;
    private int Guess1, Guess2, Guess3;
    private int guessCount;

    public void playGame() {
        if (Guess1 == 0 || Guess1 == Guess2 || Guess2 == Guess3 || Guess1 == Guess3);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter another number" +
                "the first digit can't be 0 and no digits can repeat");

        do {
            Guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a three digit number"));
        } while (Guess != randNumber);         

        if (Guess == randNumber)
            System.out.println("It took you " + guessCount + " guesses.");
    }

    private int generateSecretNumber() {
         Random randN = new Random();
         return randN.nextInt(999)+1; 
    }  

    private void printHint(String guess) {
        if (randNumber == Guess)
            System.out.println("Correct");
        else {
            Guess1 = (Guess) / 100;
            Guess2 = (Guess % 100) / 10;
            Guess3 = (Guess % 100) % 10;
        }

        if (Guess1 == Rand1) {
            System.out.println("Fermi");
        }
        if (Guess2 == Rand2) {
            System.out.println("Fermi");
        }
        if (Guess3 == Rand3) {
            System.out.println("Fermi");
        }
        if (Guess2 == Rand1) {
            System.out.println("Pico");
        }
        if (Guess3 == Rand1) {
            System.out.println("Pico");
        }
        if (Guess1 == Rand2) {
            System.out.println("Pico");
        }
        if (Guess3 == Rand2) {
            System.out.println("Pico");
        }
        if (Guess1 == Rand3) {
            System.out.println("Pico");
        }
        if (Guess2 == Rand3) {
            System.out.println("Pico");
        } else if(Guess1 != Rand1 && Guess1 != Rand2 && Guess1 != Rand3 &&
            Guess2 != Rand1 && Guess2 != Rand2 && Guess2 != Rand3 &&
            Guess3 != Rand1 && Guess3 != Rand2 && Guess3 != Rand3) {
            System.out.println("Bagels");
        }
        guessCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your should not start an variable or field name with an upper-case character.  It is a violation of a core Java style rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> generateSecretNumber and printHint methods say they are unused.

Yep, that's the core issue.

You initialize the number to be guessed to zero

```
myBagels.randNumber = 0;
```

and then never set it to another value, so your loop

```
while (Guess != randNumber);
```

will go on until someone guesses 0.

> Only thing is I'm not sure how to go about making it so they are used.

There are many options.  One option is, at the beginning of playGame(), to invoke it

```
randNumber = generateSecretNumber();
```

Comment: Thanks. How would i go about fixing the loop so it gets set to another value? Also how do I add the printHint part in so it gets used?

Comment: With my suggestion, a new random number will be set every time `playGame()` is called.  Surely you don't want to change the number after every guess?  You can call `printHint()` right after `Guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a three digit number"));`

Comment: No i don't want it to change after every guess. But then how do i make it so it won't go on until someone guesses 0? Also how exactly do i call another method? I tried return.printHint(); but its not working (illegal expression)